# What is the \ used for in python?

Tags: python, imaplib

I'm following along with a tutorial for imaplib and it uses a . I can't find any information about it anywhere.

```
stat, dta = msrvr.fetch\ (cnt[0],\ '(UID BODY[TEXT])')
```

Comment: That's invalid syntax. Are you omitting some newlines here?

Comment: I guess it was just used to escape the space or a return character

Comment: \ is used for a lot of things

Comment: Do you have a url for the tutorial page with this weird thing in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you posted is invalid syntax. You can only use `\` at the end of a line:

```
stat, dta = msrvr.fetch\
 (cnt[0],\
 '(UID BODY[TEXT])')
```

It tells Python to expect more syntax that is still part of the line; it *extends the logical line* across physical boundaries. See [*Explicit line joining*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#explicit-line-joining) in the Python reference documentation.

It's use is discouraged, and the second `\` is entirely redundant because the logical line is also extended by using parentheses. The above is better written as:

```
stat, dta = msrvr.fetch(
    cnt[0],
    '(UID BODY[TEXT])')
```

See [*Implicit line joining*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#implicit-line-joining) and the [*Python Style Guide*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length):

> The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. Long lines can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash for line continuation.

Comment: Yeah that's probably it. in the tut it didn't go on a new line though. thanks.

Comment: @EricMacLeod: then the tutorial has errors, formatting or otherwise. You may want to look elsewhere.